# Symlinks w/ Xampp Error

Tags: php, windows, apache, xampp

I currently use Xampp on Windows for a local web development. In my web root, I have symlinks to each of my projects like so:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GW9Yt.png

When the symlink is followed via explorer, it opens up the correct folder and location however, when loaded via Apache in my browser (localhost/project) I receive this error:

```
Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required     'C:/xampp/htdocs/project/index.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in Unknown on line 0
```

The file index.php is located inside the directory the symlink is directed at.

I believe this is a permission error however I cannot seem to discover what might be causing this as I have individually checked the permissions of each folder, file, etc and can't seem to find the issue.

Something I have noticed is that files located in folders located inside folders inside the symlink, e.g. link/style/file.txt will load however those in the root directory of the symlink do not.

Answer (score 5):

Even I faced the same problem while installing magento on XAMPP & Windows-7. This clearly solved my problem.

1. Stop the apache and mysql
2. Exit XAMPP
3. Click on start button and search for XAMPP
4. Right click on "XAMPP Control Panel" and "Run as administrator"
5. Now you start apache and mysql
6. Your symlinks should start working now

Comment: If this does not work you can also try executing the command by opening the terminal as administrator and do the esame thing as above, fsutil behavior set SymlinkEvaluation L2L:1 R2R:1 L2R:1 R2L:1

Comment: When you get the `symlink(): Permission denied` error in PHP, and you're using XAMPP this works great too. Thanks!